# Flask web app: How to filter database records using multiple checkboxes?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, filter, sqlalchemy

I'm working on a CRUD Flask web app that allows scheduling truck appointments. I'm able to create, update, and delete appointments, but I'm struggling to retrieve specific data from the database.

What I want to achieve is to have three checkboxes, each representing a type of material that can be shipped. When a user selects one or more checkboxes and clicks on the submit button, I want the app to display only the appointments that correspond to the selected materials in a table.

I've implemented the filtering functionality by modifying the index() function in app.py. The code below runs, but it only works for one selected material at a time:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    search_material = request.args.get('material_filter')
    appts = appts_db.query.filter_by(material=search_material) \
        .order_by(appts_db.pickup_date).all()

    return render_template('index.html', appts=appts)
```

In index.html, I have three checkboxes and a submit button:

```html
<form action="/" method="GET">
    <label>Select a material:</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="material_filter" id="HCl_filter" value="HCl">
    <label for="HCl">HCl</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="material_filter" id="Caustic_filter" value="Caustic">
    <label for="Caustic">Caustic</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="material_filter" id="Bleach_filter" value="Bleach">
    <label for="Bleach">Bleach</label><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter Appointments">
</form>

<h3>Appointment List:</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Carrier</th>
        <th>Material</th>
        <th>Pickup Date [YYYY-MM-DD]</th>
    </tr>

    {% for appt in appts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ appt.carrier }}</td>
            <td>{{ appt.material }}</td>
            <td>{{ appt.pickup_date }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

What changes do I need to make to allow selecting multiple materials and display those in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two changes needed to make this work.

First of all, `request.args.get` will only retrieve a single value from the form data.  This is usually OK, but not if the form has multiple inputs with the same `name` attribute.  In this case, we must use `request.args.getlist` to get all the values as a `list`.

Secondly, the `filter_by` method cannot express selecting from a list of values for the same attribute.  In this case, we want to use `.filter` in combination with the attribute's `.in_` method.

So the route should look like this:

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Get values for all of the material_filter inputs.
    search_materials = request.args.getlist('material_filter')
    # Select all rows that match the inputs.
    appts = appts_db.query.filter(appts_db.material.in_(search_materials)) \
        .order_by(appts_db.pickup_date).all()
    return render_template('index.html', appts=appts)
```